# emacs 26.1 windows site-lisp directory & site-start.el

Tags: emacs

Подскажите, что стало с site-lisp директорией? Не нахожу в дистрибутиве, попытка создания emacsdir/site-lisp/site-start.el не приводит к результату.

Из Emacs выпилили вообще эту директорию?
Или это особенность windows-версии?
Или site-start.el не загружается, а вместо него надо что-то другое создавать?

Мнe нужен файл, который загрузится ДО ~/.emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл: emacs/share/emacs/26.1/site-lisp/

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/266894)

Comment: @Темкатоже, это ответ с путём, который он искал.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю свой ответ.

Что бы не гадать, есть стандартный способ узнать, что и от куда грузится в Emacs

<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> load-path <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
load-path - load-path is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Documentation:
List of directories to search for files to load.
Each element is a string (directory file name) or nil (meaning
‘default-directory’).
This list is consulted by the ‘require’ function.
Initialized during startup as described in Info node ‘(elisp)Library Search’.
Use ‘directory-file-name’ when adding items to this path.  However, Lisp
programs that process this list should tolerate directories both with
and without trailing slashes.
```